# Right HTTP code for adult content block

Tags: seo, html, http, nofollow, adult-content

I have a site with User Generated Content. Although only a small amount of it is Adult content, part of that has become popular in search engines in foreign languages.

To avoid being classified somehow related to such content, I'm blocking these page's content, and allowing users that really want to view it to click a nofollow link that shows it. What status code should the page return?

Answer (score 1):

Those pages should still return a status 200 OK header response.

You'd just serve a `meta="noindex, nofollow"` in the  of those pages to prevent Google from crawling and indexing them.

Comment: would that be considered a soft 404 because the page is almost empty?

Comment: I don't follow, why would the page be almost empty? Are these articles, categories, navigation - what type of content is on the pages that you don't want indexed?

Comment: These pages have content that I've identified as pornography. I don't want users to accidentally be exposed to such content so I'm keeping these pages empty with a link to the unblocked content. Makes sense?